# Single board computer (SBC) with industrial grade

Tags: sbc

I was using single board computer (Raspberry Pi, Beaglebone) to develop prototypes. A new requirement is that the prototype should satisfy "**industrial grade**" with regarding to (for example):

```
Temperature (e.g. -40 to 85 degree)
humidity
life cycle (e.g. 10 years)
mean time between failure (MTBF) (e.g. > 80,000 ~ 100,000 hours)
```

For another example, I find one of the issue is: many SBC uses SD card to load OS. I guess most SD card cannot run for years without stopping.

Meanwhile, the SBC should also support similar functionalities (e.g. Linux OS, required physical interfaces, enough memory). (I guess this is not a potential problem).

How can I find such industrial grade SBCs? Many commercial products (e.g. firewall hardware) can satisfy industrial grade. Where do their SBCs come from?

Comment: Some work has been done in that area, the 85° is a bummer though, maybe you are able to talk that requirement away.
https://www.netiot.com/netpi/industrial-raspberry-pi-3/
https://revolution.kunbus.de/

Comment: [Shopping questions are off topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You need to get a distributor; good ones will speak to you on the phone or send a rep to discuss requirements. Provided you're planning a sufficiently large purchase.

Comment: Stiff requirements.  You need a producer that has produced and tested enough products to get a valid MTBF calculation.  Temperature may be a bummer but do-able, but MTBF and life cycle may be the killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rating of a product for environmental conditions is more than the sum of its components.

So, yes, you sure don't want to use an SBC with the cheapest allwinner SoC but rather something based on chips that are specified for a larger temperature range(look at the SoCs of eg. NXP and TI), but the rating of your overall product stems from your product design - for example, a chip that is solidly connected thermally to the case might happily work at 65°C environment temperature, because it won't get much warmer when cooling is good.

To get a device certified for industrial environmental conditions, **you** need to do the whole-system testing of the complete device; looking at its components won't get you far.